# Creating the iphone list style on ActionScript 3 on flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Hello im trying to achive the iphone list effect in AS3 but i cant get a good result, dont you know a good script for doing this? Thanks!

Comment: What is "iphone list effect", can you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might be referring to the act of swiping (clicking+dragging on a computer) up and down a list, with some simple easing added.  I would consider building this yourself using AS3's dragging methods, and applying some basic easing with a library like TweenLite.

If you want to copy/purchase a script from somewhere, it might be tough to find exactly what you want.  My guess is that you'll have the best luck trying to find a simple scrollbar component with built-in easing (ie. http://www.extendstudio.com/flash-components-creative-flash-scroller-extension/features.html) , and customize the hit area of the scrollbar to overlay on top of your scrollable content.  This way, clicking and dragging anywhere will produce the desired effect.